# Lauch and Splash screen issue for Lite and pro version for iOS app on iPhone 5

Tags: iphone-5, targets

I have developed an iOS Universal app that is to be supported for iPhone 5 screens.Now the hing is that the application is supporting Lite and Pro version and they are housed in the same Xcode project.Now each target has its own Splash and launching screen that can be differentiated.The issue is that with iPhone 5 screen support how can i achieve this ? I could not found the enough details in pList settings to make a separate screen for Lite and pro version that can be visible on Iphone 5 ? All suggestions are welcome and thanks in advance to all geeks.